# How to send request with null user agent?

Tags: http, debugging, user-agent

In my webapp I am getting key errors for requests with no user agent.

How can I make a request with no user agent to debug and test this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48223/how-to-send-get-post-requests-without-header-and-agent-information

```
nc example.com 80 << http_message_file
```

Did not load the request in the file, rather let me type it using a here DOC.

```
cat http_message_file | nc example.com 80
```

Did the trick

Answer (score 0):

```sh
curl -H "User-Agent:" example.com
```

That will overwrite the default user agent sent by curl and instead show as null on the server.